# How to skip a layer in a Keras/Openvino model

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, openvino

I'm trying skip unnecessary Transpose operations that were added previously due to the conversion process from PyTorch to Tensorflow. Any suggestions?

The model has 2 outputs and I'm trying to remove the Transpose operations from on branch of outputs. And the Transpose operation is added during the process of converting from OpenVino to Tensorflow

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Was able to achieve it with ONNX, Netron, and the sclblonnx python library.

I used the python library to delete and re-route the output of the node before the Transpose. And used Netron to display the ONNX graph and know what the name of that output data is:

[image]

Minimized example:

```
import sclblonnx as so
g = so.graph_from_file('/path/to/onnx/file')
g = so.delete_node(g, "Transpose_178")
idx = -1
for i,elem in enumerate(g.node):
  if elem.name == "Softmax_179":
    idx = i

g.node[i].input[0] = '570'
so.graph_to_file(g, '/home/cw/Openvino/ERFNet/ERF_lane_so.onnx' )
```